# Return BadCredentials Exception as Json - Spring Boot 3.2

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, exception, tomcat

I have a Spring Boot service that uses Spring Security for authentication. I am checking the credentials in a custom AuthenticationProvider like this:

```
@Component
class CustomAuthenticationProvider(private val userService: IUserService)
: AuthenticationProvider {

 @Throws(AuthenticationException::class, UsernameNotFoundException::class, BadCredentialsException::class)
 override fun authenticate(authentication: Authentication): Authentication {
    val username: String = authentication.principal.toString()
    val password: String = authentication.credentials.toString()
    val encoder = BCryptPasswordEncoder()

    val user = userService.getUser(username) ?: throw UsernameNotFoundException("User not found")
    if (user.accountStatus == "deactivated")
        throw UsernameNotFoundException("User was deleted")
    if (!encoder.matches(password, user.password)) {
        throw BadCredentialsException("1000")
    }
    return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, emptyList())
}

override fun supports(authentication: Class<*>): Boolean {
    return (authentication == UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken::class.java)
}
}
```

When the user credentials are not correct I receive an error like this in the client:

```
Error when logging in  Error transferring https:..... - server replied: 
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-color:#525D76;} h1 {font-size:22px;} h2 {font-size:16px;} h3 {font-size:14px;} p {font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style></head><body><h1>HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden</h1><hr class="line" /><p><b>Type</b> Status Report</p><p><b>Message</b> Access Denied</p><p><b>Description</b> The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.</p><hr class="line" /><h3>Apache Tomcat/10.1.17</h3></body></html>
```

I would like to receive an exception message encapsulated in a Json such that I can parse it and give an appropriate response to the user.

I was not able to implement this. I looked up and found that there are methods to handle exceptions that occur inside controllers. In my case the exceptions are thrown in the AuthenticationProvider. How should I handle this problem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will study this and let you know.

Comment: Yes. I confirm it is the answer to my question. For me it was not so obvious at the beginning, but after carefull study this is the solution : defining an authenticationentrypoint and reference it in the websecurityconfig.